# Adding or assigning an integer literal to a size_t

Tags: c, c89, size-t

In C I see a lot of code that adds or assigns an integer literal to a `size_t` variable.

```
size_t foo = 1;
foo += 1;
```

What conversion takes place here, and can it ever happen that a `size_t` is "upgraded" to an `int` and then converted back to a `size_t`? Would that still wraparound if I was at the max?

```
size_t foo = SIZE_MAX;
foo += 1;
```

Is that defined behavior? It's an unsigned type `size_t` which is having a signed `int` added to it (that may be a larger type?) and the converted back to a `size_t`. Is there risk of signed integer overflow?

Would it make sense to write something like `foo + bar + (size_t)1` instead of `foo + bar + 1`? I never see code like that, but I'm wondering if it's necessary if integer promotions are troublesome.

C89 doesn't say how a `size_t` will be ranked or what exactly it is:

> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integral type) is size_t defined in the  header.

Comment: Good question. From experience, `size_t` is the same size or larger than `int` on every implementation that I've ever used. If we were allowed to apply common sense to this (which of course we're not), we would note that an `int` is the "natural" size for an integer type on any given implementation, and therefore it would make no sense for `size_t` to be smaller than that natural size.

Comment: Note that `SIZE_MAX` was not defined by the C89 standard.

Comment: Is this question about the current standard or C89?

Comment: @user3386109 An embedded system with a 32-bit CPU but 64KB or less of storage, would be a natural candidate for 16-bit `size_t`.  These days it's probably cheaper to get 1GB of storage than 64KB though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current C standard allows for a possibility of an implementation that would cause undefined behavior when executing the following code, however such implementation does not exist, and probably never will:

```
size_t foo = SIZE_MAX;
foo += 1;
```

The type size_t is as unsigned type<sup>1</sup>, with a minimum range:<sup>2</sup> [0,65535].

The type size_t may be defined as a synonym for the type unsigned short. The type unsigned short may be defined having 16 precision bits, with the range: [0,65535]. In that case the value of SIZE_MAX is 65535.

The type int may be defined having 16 precision bits (plus one sign bit), two's complement representation, and range: [-65536,65535].

The expression foo += 1, is equivalent to foo = foo + 1 (except that foo is evaluated only once but that is irrelevant here). The variable foo will get promoted using integer promotions<sup>3</sup>. It will get promoted to type int because type int can represent all values of type size_t and rank of size_t, being a synonym for unsigned short, is lower than  the rank of int. Since the maximum values of size_t, and int are the same, the computation causes a signed overflow, causing undefined behavior.

This holds for the current standard, and it should also hold for C89 since it doesn't have any stricter restrictions on types.

Solution for avoiding signed overflow for any imaginable implementation is to use an unsigned int integer constant:

```
foo += 1u;
```

In that case if foo has a lower rank than int, it will be promoted to unsigned int using usual arithmetic conversions.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899/201x 7.19 Common definitions  2)
size_t
which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899/201x 7.20.3 Limits of other integer types 2)
limit of size_t
SIZE_MAX  65535

<sup>3</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899/201x 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers 2)
The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
be used:
An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int)
whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and
unsigned int.
If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned
int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the
integer promotions.

Comment: There was a mistake actually, which is now fixed. The int should have a precision of 16 bits, because the sign bit isn't counted as a precision bit. The width of the type int is therefore 17 bits plus any padding bits this abstract implementation holds.

Comment: A _good_ answer to OP's given scenario. I am certain no platform today would have `size_t` as `unsigned short` with the same positive range as `int` as you also suggested.  And hope no future novel machine does either.

Comment: If the maximum value of `int` is larger than `size_t` and the `size_t` is converted to int and the value is added, and the result doesn't exceed `INT_MAX`, then it is defined behavior when that integer result is converted back to size_t? For example `INT_MAX == 6` and `SIZE_MAX == 4` and `size_t foo = 4; foo += 2;` then is it defined that when that result 6 is assigned to foo there is no undefined behavior, and it instead wraps around to 1?

Comment: @newguy Yes. But if you add 3 to foo, you get undefined behavior. The solution I showed in my answer, using an unsigned int constant works everytime and for any value.

Comment: I have marked this as correct since it is correct but also it was easiest to understand.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, since `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integral type.

Operations involving a `size_t` will therefore introduce promotions, but these depend on what `size_t` actually is, and what other types involved in the expression actually are.

If `size_t` was equivalent to a `unsigned short` (e.g. a 16-bit type) then

```
size_t foo = 1;
foo += 1;
```

would (semantically) promote `foo` to a `int`, add `1`, and then convert the result back to `size_t` for storing in `foo`.    (I say "semantically", because that is the meaning of the code according to the standard.  A compiler is free to apply the "as if" rule - i.e. do anything it likes, as long as it delivers the same net effect).

On another hand, if `size_t` was equivalent to a `long long unsigned` (e.g. a 64-bit signed type), then the same code would promote `1` to be of type `long long unsigned`, add that to the value of `foo`, and store the result back into `foo`.

In both cases, the net result is the same unless an overflow occurs.   In this case, there is no overflow, since an both `int` and `size_t` are guaranteed able to represent the values `1` and `2`.

If an overflow occurs (e.g. adding a larger integral value), then the behaviour can vary.  Overflow of a signed integral type (e.g. `int`) results in undefined behaviour.   Overflow of an `unsigned` integral type uses modulo arithmetic.

As to the code

```
size_t foo = SIZE_MAX;
foo += 1;
```

it is possible to do the same sort of analysis.

If `size_t` is equivalent to a `unsigned short` then `foo` would be converted to `int`.   If `int` is equivalent to a `signed short`, it cannot represent the value of `SIZE_MAX`, so the conversion will overflow, and the result is undefined behaviour.    If `int` is able to represent a larger range than `short int` (e.g. it is equivalent to `long`), then the conversion of `foo` to `int` will succeed, incrementing that value will succeed, and storing back to `size_t` will use modulo arithmetic and produce the result of `0`.

If `size_t` is equivalent to `unsigned long`, then the value `1` will be converted to `unsigned long`, adding that to `foo` will use modulo arithmetic (i.e. produce a result of zero), and that will be stored into `foo`.

It is possible to do similar analyses assuming that `size_t` is actually other unsigned integral types.

Note:   In modern systems, a `size_t` that is the same size or smaller than an `int` is unusual.    However, such systems have existed (e.g. Microsoft and Borland C compilers targeting 16-bit MS-DOS on hardware with an 80286 CPU).  There are also 16-bit microprocessors still in production, mostly for use in embedded systems with lower power usage and low throughput requirements, and C compilers that target them (e.g. Keil C166 compiler which targets the Infeon XE166 microprocessor family).   [Note:  I've never had reason to use the Keil compiler but, given its target platform, it would not be a surprise if it supports a 16-bit `size_t` that is the same size or smaller than the native `int` type on that platform].

Comment: "size_t was equivalent to a unsigned short" and ... "would (semantically) promote `foo` to a int".  Maybe.   In such a case, more _likely_, `int` is also 16-bit. and `foo` becomes an `unsigned`.  The "If `size_t` is equivalent to a `unsigned short` .. " is impacted in the same fashion.  No UB.

Comment: DOS used 16-bit `int`, `unsigned`, `short`, `unsinged short` and `size_t`.  `size_t` was not _smaller_, yet the same size.  In particular, `size_t` cannot be 16-bit `signed int`.  The narrowest it can be is 16-bit some unsigned type/

Comment: `size_t` is a *quasi-unsigned* type that is defined over the positive values for type `int` (e.g. between `0` and `(1U << 31) - 1` (`2147483648`) for x86/x86_64)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you quote the standard on that?

Comment: @chux Peter is talking about a situation where the precisions of signed short, unsigned short, signed int, and unsigned int, are the same. In that case USHRT_MAX equals INT_MAX. This is allowed by the standard. In that case an unsigned short is promoted to int. If the value of the unsigned short was USHRT_MAX the operation on the promoted operand does a signed overflow and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Your promotion scenario is not possible. If `int` is the same size as `short`, then a type the same size as `unsigned short` will not be promoted to `int`. (It will be promoted to `unsigned int`). There is no possibility of UB.

Comment: size_t size is the length of a pointer on machine and it is unsigned type. This is the definition of size_t.

Comment: @Radon no, that's not the definition of size_t. It has nothing to do with the "length of a pointer"

Comment: Yes it does, size_t range is the same as machine adress space. On 16 bit machines its same as uint16_t, on 32 bit machines its same as uint32_t and on 64 bit machine its same as uint64_t. Its safe to cast any pointer you have to size_t.

Comment: @2501 the gnu implementation, not the C11 draft.

Comment: @2501 Agree with the theoretical [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187755/adding-or-assigning-an-integer-literal-to-a-size-t/40188014?noredirect=1#comment67644753_40188014), but this answer's DOS example does not apply.  Do you have an real-life example that meets your scenario?

Comment: @Randon.  Disagree with "size_t range is the same as machine address space".  That may be your experience but `size_t`not defined that limited way in C.  I have worked on compliant machines that have `size_t` narrow than pointers.

Comment: @M.M Agree with your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) as _practically_ true in 2016, but C allows `UINT_MAX`, `INT_MAX`, `USHORT_MAX` and `SHORT_MAX` to all have the same value.  Such machines (which does not apply to DOS ones) are rare today.  In such a machine, with promotion,`unsigned short` --> `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`foo += 1` means `foo = foo + 1`. If `size_t` is narrower than `int` (that is, `int` can represent all values of `size_t`), then `foo` is promoted to `int` in the expression `foo + 1`.

The only way this could overflow is if `INT_MAX` == `SIZE_MAX`. Theoretically that is possible, e.g. 16-bit int and 15-bit `size_t`. (The latter probably would have 1 padding bit).

More likely, `SIZE_MAX` will be less than `INT_MAX`, so the code will be *implementation-defined* due to out-of-range assignment. Normally the implementation definition is the "obvious" one, high bits are discarded, so the result will be `0`.

As a practical decision I would not recommend mangling your code to cater to these cases (15-bit `size_t`, or non-obvious implementation-definition) which probably have never happened and never will. Instead, you could do some compile-time tests that will give an error if these cases do occur.  A compile-time assertion that `INT_MAX < SIZE_MAX` would be practical in this day and age.

Comment: size_t cannot have a precision of 15 bits. Please see my answer where I explain how this is possible with a slightly different configuration.

Comment: @2501 - Based on what? Standard, or current known implementations?

Comment: @2501 good point. I'll have to increase my answer by 1 bit :P  Although apparently that limit did not appear in C89, which is what OP is asking about