# Why this code is printing "False", though size of int is greater than -1?

Tags: c, sizeof

According to the code below, size of int is not greater than -1. Why is it so? Why "False" was printed instead of "True"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    if(sizeof(int) > -1) {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("False\n");
    }

    // Here size of int is equals to 4
    printf("Size of int: %ld\n", sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `sizeof` returns `size_t` which is unsigned and when it is compared with `int` the int is promoted to unsigned and the bit representation all 1's now considered as unsigned, which is bigger than `-1` and also that of `sizeof int`. That's why this result.

Correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: Ah! I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Is this actually a *promotion* or a *conversion*?

Comment: @水飲み鳥.: Yes....

Comment: What is standard saying about the rank of `size_t`? Because if it is lower than of the `int`, then the conversion will go the other way around, and it will eventually come `True`.

Comment: @EugeneSh..: Ah yes that's what I am saying - AFAICR, unsigned higher rank than signed.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187755/adding-or-assigning-an-integer-literal-to-a-size-t) `size_t` *might* have a lower rank (well, that would be uncommon).

Comment: @EugeneSh..: Ah yes the most usual case is what I have said in the comment but it's not the only one. You are right that if rank of int is lower o than rank of int (because of size) it will be **true**.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Thanks for noting. C has these charms,. Let me know if you find anything interesting.